# Issues in Rooting Android Manually

Tags: rooting

My android device is 4.4.2.

I am trying to root my android device manually.

I have gone through the [link](http://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-root-any-android-device-manually.586982/).

As per that link, after running following **adb shell** commands

adb shell

->chmod 6755 /data/local/tmp/su

->chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox

->chmod 644 /data/local/tmp/Superuser.apk

Its recommended to put Android device into Download mode by holding down the Volume up button and simultaneously turn on the phone using the power on switch.

In case of my device, after holding down the Volume up button and simultaneously turn on the phone using the power on switch, I see Recovery Mode then I see following screen.

[image]

Please let me know, what option I need to select.

Also at the end its recommended to pull out the battery from your Android device. My android device is tablet whose battery is not removable.

Please let me know what I need to do in this case?

Regards

EinfoMail

Comment: That is, as you already pointed out, *recovery mode*. As you wrote you need to boot into "Download mode", which usually is [bootloader](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bootloader/info) mode. Though following that description I somehow doubt it: in download mode, the device can only be accessed by tools like Odin, Heimdall & Fastboot, which work on partition level. I don't see how one can copy files the way described. But well, might be something specific to the devices named there. I had rather expected a custom recovery with ADB built in being behind it.

Comment: I have gone through many links for rooting android manually. In many links, I didn’t see this step ‘Put Android device into Download mode by holding down the Volume up button and simultaneously turn on the phone using the power on switch.” So ignoring this step, please let me know as per my device what I need to do after executing adb shell commands so that I can root successfully.

Comment: Performing the steps following the "put it into download mode" requires root access to be present (and the `/system` partition being mounted read-write). The only way I see for that is via a custom recovery which runs the ADB daemon in "insecure mode" (i.e. as root). With that given, the next steps sound reasonable. Without that, they should fail as you cannot write the files where they must be placed. OTOH, if you have a custom recovery, it would be much easier to simply flash the `SuperSU.zip` straight away. But for sure, the `<3e>` recovery (=stock) cannot be used for that.

Comment: Earlier I tried many times for unlocking OEM and flashing Custom ROM in my device but even going through proper steps, I am not able to unlock OEM and also I don’t find Custom ROM for my device. The only steps I can go through is rooting my device. And I believe you mean to say, as per my device, rooting manually is more complicated/ not supported or it’s not recommended. Am I right?

Comment: Not being familiar with your device, I cannot tell. And it sounds even the creator of the post you refer to just copied the text without verification. Sorry I cannot be of better assistance to you – but I'm afraid I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Please understand. There is no text without verification. Sometimes because of unstable Internet connection, I prefer to type my question/ comment in Word. And once connection becomes stable, I copy my question/ comment from file. I have been using rooted android device for last one and half year. Also I tried multiple times to unlock OEM and flash Custom Recovery/ ROM but its failed. From beginning, I have been using Kingo Root but now I am facing issue with Kingo Root.  And some apps show error message and some are not in English language. That’s why I was trying to root manually.

Comment: I was referring to the page you've linked: ***This is not my tutorial and i have not tested this […]*** Apart from that, as I wrote, I cannot help any further, sorry.

Comment: I do agree, you haven’t tested it. Before putting my question here, I tried to resolve it by self after going through various links and just for a reference, I put a link here. Now I am not going to be sticky for rooting manually so leave it. Would like to help me in regards of Kingo Root?

Comment: Agreed, I've tested it neither. But please read again: that was a quote from the tutorial you linked, he didn't test it either. And sorry, as I wrote: I'm out. Never used Kingo or the likes. I always took care to only buy devices which had an approved and trusted process for rooting.

Comment: That’s good. I read many links for rooting, custom recovery and custom rom. Also I rooted my device earlier. However, I am very far from proficiency and there are a lot of stuffs that I need to know in this regard. At the end, please help me positively for one point. May I know, what are the approved and trusted process for rooting, flashing custom recovery and flashing custom rom? For your convenience, please provide me links. I’ll go through.

Comment: May I recommend you our [rooting tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) for that? And to follow up the relevant links from there?